# Why does docker run -t keep the bash process from exiting and stopping the container

Tags: bash, docker

I understand that a docker container will stop once the main process (the command) ends.

I also understand that the -t will allocate a pseudo TTY

```
docker run -t <image> <command>
```

Now, when I run bash by default the container stops immediately, which is expected

```
docker run fedora bash
docker -ps =>(this gives empty list)
```

But when I run bash with -t like this

```
docker run -t fedora bash
[CTRL+C]
docker ps =>(this shows one running container)
```

Why does -t keep the bash process running? Although the same -t will not keep, for example, echo running

```
docker run -t fedora echo "hello"
[CTRL+C]
docker ps =>(this shows empty list although we added -t)
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use `bash` without `-t` it exits with status 0 immediately since you're not supplying any command to `bash` using `-c` option.

By using `-t` you are allocating a pseudo-tty to `bash` process. However you're not using another important `-i` option that keeps `STDIN` open even if not attached. Without `-i` you cannot type anything inside the `bash` hence `bash` keeps running waiting for the next command.

`echo` command exits with status 0 immediately because `echo` is not an interactive process like `bash`.

So right way to start `bash` is:

```
docker run -it fedora bash
```

As per [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use `-i -t` together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. `-i -t` is often written `-it`.